# How to pragmatically create and load multiple views in a Cocoa Desktop Application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've been trying to create multiple custom views generating xibs and connecting controllers to them.
i have tried things like

```
[window AddSubView:view0]
```

and

```
[window setContentView:view0]
```

but i still don't get the new view displayed.

i think I'm doing it wrong since creating the xib file.

what is the right way from creating the xib files and the controllers to displaying custom views?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Verify that view0 is wired properly in Interface Builder, or if it was created manually, show us the code from which you created it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll after some... hard researching i got things working the way i want

here's my code

```
- (IBAction)showFirstView:(id)sender{
    theDetailViewController = [DetailViewController new];
    [theDetailViewController initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    NSView *splitRightView = [[theSplitView subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSView *aDetailView = [theDetailViewController view];
    [aDetailView setFrame:[splitRightView bounds]];
    [aDetailView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
    [splitRightView addSubview:aDetailView];
    NSLog(@"%@",(NSString *)splitRightView);
}
```

what i was doing wrong was creating a class as *NSView* instead of *NSViewController*
and trying to load the view just like that but you need to create a *NSViewController* and set this as the File's Owner class of the custom view XIB and then set the outlet VIEW to point at your custom view.

Thanks ya'll 4 your help.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [window AddSubView:view0]
> ```

Windows aren't views in Cocoa, and nothing responds to `AddSubView:` anyway. (Remember that selectors are case-sensitive.)

> ```
> [window setContentView:view0]
> ```

That *is* valid, but you'd want to make sure that `view0`'s frame has the same size as `window`'s content rectangle.

> but i still don't get the new view displayed.

One possibility is that you are not actually talking to a window. You probably either haven't hooked up your `window` outlet or haven't loaded the nib with that window in it yet or, if `window` isn't an outlet and the window doesn't exist in a nib, you haven't created it in code yet. Either way, your `window` variable is `nil`, so you are sending messages such as `addSubview:` to `nil`, which does nothing.

If you have proven with `NSLog` or the debugger that you do, in fact, have a window to send messages to, and you still have the problem, make sure you are ordering the window in. If the window is in a nib, you may want to turn on “Visible at Launch” (which actually means “Visible at Nib Load”); otherwise, order the window in yourself by sending it a `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` message.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Hillegass - Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X (3rd edition), Chapter 29. View Swapping